# Where can I find old versions of SQL Developer (4.x)?

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I need a version that works with 11.2.0.4 driver or lower.

In Oracle site there is the [current version 20.4.1](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html) and a link to the previous one. Each previous version you click has a link to the previous one, but this chain is broken.

20.4.1 points to 20.4 that points to 20.2 that points to 19.4. The last link is broken.

For some reason, there is a forgotten [link to 3.2.2](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/opensource/sqldev-v322-downloads.html) version that google was able to find.

Do you guys know of any repository for archived versions?

Comment: Assuming you have a support contract, you can generally raise a MOS ticket to get access to archived versions of software.

Comment: Why would this be necessary? I want an old version because I have an old product whose support is long gone. Also, isn't it free to download and use?

Comment: Oracle doesn't generally make the effort to keep old versions of software available for download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle removed the links, but the files are still there.

Example: http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-no-jre.zip

Of course before using that direct link, you need to go to any other public download page and accept the license agreement, but after that, it works.

Also the full clients contain some old SQL Developer versions.

11.2.0.4 client (for example: p13390677_112040_MSWIN-x86-64_4of7.zip) contains SQL Developer 1.55.

12.1.0.2 client (for example: p21419221_121020_MSWIN-x86-64_7of10.zip) contains SQL Developer 3.2.20.10.

I did not check newer versions.

You can download those files from https://support.oracle.com/, or any random site you can find with a Google search using the above filenames.

Answer (score 5):

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-22.2.1.234.1810-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-22.2.1.234.1810-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-21.4.1.349.1822-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-21.4.1.349.1822-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.0.379.2205-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.4.0.379.2205-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.2.0.175.1842-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.2.0.175.1842-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-19.4.0.354.1759-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-19.4.0.354.1759-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-19.2.0.206.2117-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-19.2.0.206.2117-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-19.1.0.094.2042-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-19.1.0.094.2042-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.4.0-376.1900-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.4.0-376.1900-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.3.0.277.2354-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.3.0.277.2354-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.1.0.095.1630-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-18.1.0.095.1630-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-17.4.0.355.2349-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-17.4.0.355.2349-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-17.3.1.279.0537-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-17.3.1.279.0537-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-17.2.0.188.1159-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-17.2.0.188.1159-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.2.0.17.089.1709-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.2.0.17.089.1709-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.5.21.78-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.5.21.78-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.2.20.64-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.2.20.64-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.1.19.59-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.1.19.59-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.0.19.07-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.0.18.37-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.0.18.37-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.1.0.17.29-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.1.14.48-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.1.14.48-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.0.13.80-x64.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-4.0.0.13.80-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-3.2.20.09.87.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper64-3.2.20.09.87-no-jre.zip

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-3.1.07.42.zip
https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper64-3.1.07.42-no-jre.zip

To know more about the versions available I found Table A-1 useful:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/20.4/dmrig/oracle-data-miner-releases.html#GUID-534E7398-93C1-41FD-80E4-CE40B2021813